# Same presentation topic for different conferences

Tags: conference

Is it possible to give the same presentation, e.g., invited talk, tutorials, and like (same topic, slight change in abstract and other parts) in different conferences? Is there any plagiarism issue like with papers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Under what circumstances can one republish a conference paper/presentation?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2673/under-what-circumstances-can-one-republish-a-conference-paper-presentation)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. Although the title of the other question mentions presentations, the question doesn't at all.

Comment: @shoover, I am taking about Tutorials, more specific invited talk. It's not about normal paper presentation like oral presentation or poster.

Comment: @shoover: Also that question is about fields where conferences are a primary mechanism of publication, which is a small minority.

Comment: I just picked one that sounded the closest, and OP did say "presentations" after all. There were bunches of questions about reusing material...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's entirely reasonable to give the same (or nearly the same) presentation for different audiences.  This frequently happens with invited talks, which are often expected to present a survey rather than a particular new result.  Thus, there is no expectation of novelty and thus no issue with plagiarism.

If you are presenting on a paper, on the other hand, the talk should be novel simply because it is about a paper that is novel.